# How we can make composite primary key and pass it into an other table as a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a junction  table named as result.I am trying to make a composite primary key and trying to an other table as a foreign key.But I don't know how have to make  **strong text**composite primary key and pass it into another table as foreign key.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to do this through the design tools in Management Studio or by writing SQL?

Comment: By writing sql.SQL server 2008